# Simple repeating level system

Tags: python

Trying to prototype a simple leveling system where you can add or subtract xp, every time the user levels up the xp needed to level up again should increase by 100 and the users xp should go back down keeping any xp over the needed amount. So far all of those things mentioned sort of work however it seems if I go past a couple level the program break I don't get any errors this is probably a simple fix but I'm stuck.

```
level = 0
next_level = 100
current_xp = 0
xp_to_next_level = 100

runtest = True
levelup = True

while runtest:
    xp_added = int(input('Add xp: '))
    current_xp = current_xp + xp_added
    if current_xp < next_level:
        xp_to_next_level = next_level - current_xp
        print('Your level is '+str(level))
        print('Your current xp is '+str(current_xp))
        print('Xp to next level is '+str(xp_to_next_level))
        print()
        continue
    
    while levelup:
        if current_xp >= next_level:
            print('Level Up!')
            print()
            level = level + 1
            current_xp =  current_xp - next_level
            next_level = 100 * (level + 1 )
            xp_to_next_level = next_level - current_xp
            print('Your level is '+str(level))
            print('Your current xp is '+str(current_xp))
            print('Xp to next level is '+str(xp_to_next_level))
            print()
            continue
            
        else:
            levelup = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for other ways to improve your code, **modularity** is often a big one

```py
# a function which returns the amount of xp needed to pass a level
def xp_per_level(level):
    return (level + 1) * 100

# a function which wraps around the xp and changes the level
def update_level(xp, level):
    while xp >= xp_per_level(level):
        xp -= xp_per_level(level)
        level += 1
    while xp < 0:
        level -= 1
        xp += xp_per_level(level)
    return xp, level


level = 0
xp = 0

while True:
    xp += int(input('enter change in xp: '))
    # since update_level returns two values, we need to "unpack" both here
    xp, level = update_level(xp, level)
```

This lets you separate your logic into clear functions, and have greater control over the amount of xp needed to pass a level. In the example above, the player moves from level 0 to 1 once they reach 100xp, and from 1 to 2 at 200xp etc just as you want.

Hope it helps to provide an alternative structure, even though the logic is almost the same :)

**Edit: Added `xp_to_next_level` function**

```py
def xp_to_next_level(xp, level):
    # this works by subtracting the current xp from max xp for that level
    return xp_per_level(level) - xp
```

Comment: I really like this format and I beleive I understand it but when I tried to incorporate a xp_to_next_level variable I eneded up with valueerror: too many values to unpack (expected 2). I made sure to add xp_to_next_level to all the right spots , I defined it as 0 with the other variables before the main while loop. And I added it as parameters as needed in the main while loop and in the function. And i added it as xp_to_next_level = xp_per_level(level) - xp in both of the while loops inside the function update_level.

Comment: The error you're getting suggests you've used the `update_level` function a little wrong. This function returns **two** values: `xp, level`, meaning that whenever you get the return value of this function you also need to "unpack" them: `xp, level = update_level(...)` (notice the *two* variables on the left hand side). I'll update my example with an `xp_to_next_level` function to help :)

Comment: Using that function I just print it as a string along with some dialouge right after the update level function and it seems to be working as intended thanks.